# TabView background transparency doesn't work as expected with ScrollView inside VStack on iOS 15

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm drawing the navigation bar manually so I place content of the screen inside `VStack`.

Besides the navigation title, there's a table. I'm using `ScrollView`+`LazyVStack`, but switching to `Table` doesn't solve the problem.

Here's a sample code:

```
TabView {
    VStack {
        Text("Title")
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack {
                ForEach(0..<100, id: \.self) {
                    Text("cell \($0)")
                }
            }
        }
    }.tabItem {
        Image(systemName: "1.square.fill")
        Text("First")
    }
}
```

On iOS 14 this works as expected:

[image]

But on iOS 15 background is always transparent:

[image]

This problem seems to be related to the new scroll edge behavior of the `UITabBar`, which is supposed to hide the background when the scrolling view reaches the end.

I know I can disable it with `UITabBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance`, but I would like to find a way to leave it enabled and working.

Comment: I'd have to assume this is just a SwiftUI bug. Probably the `LazyVStack` not knowing it's true height and so it doesn't correctly know where the end is, possibly?

Comment: It is not clear what do you want - it is known new appearance default behaviour and it is known solution, which all of us done for iOS 15+, and you know it as well, so what's the problem?

Comment: it appears this is expected behaviour as stated by @Asperi. Have you tried creating a custom navigation bar instead?

Answer (score 4):

You should clerly clip the content view inside a scrollview.

```
struct DemoView: View {
//    init() { // This works 100%
//        UITabBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
//    }
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            VStack {
                Text("Title")
                ScrollView {
                    LazyVStack {
                        ForEach(0..<100, id: \.self) {
                            Text("cell \($0)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .background(Color.blue) // remove this after test
            .clipped() // BUT HERE IS THE SOLUTION
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "1.square.fill")
                Text("First")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This new behavior of scrollview may affect to navigationbar on the top. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, @ngbaanh. I like your solution. It's not perfect, because (as you said) it affects top navigation. Also tabview looks a bit different, because we don't have content behind translucent tabs. But still much better than tabs without any background.

I think that adding .clipped() on ScrollView works good too, instead of VStack level. And After removing blue background. Just the ScrollView is clipped, tab's background is white and top nav is not affected.

Comment: And there's a Blur effect on NavigationBar or TabBar when scrolling content behind it (it's clear if you scroll an image rather than texts). So if you clipped the content in your scrollview, you may lost this effect.

Comment: Yes, true. But at least it doesn't clip top bar with title. If you have a grouped list, background of the view is gray. And clipping whole VStack may clip gray background behind title. Anyways, not perfect, but good workaround. It's just good to know there are few options and their limitations. Thanks again

Comment: @mallow I have the same problem. Use clipped() affect the top unsafe area. But if I add modifier: edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top), top unsafe area is normal. Environment: Xcode 13.4